# Usage of "umfasst"

Tags: word-order, verb-usage

I want to say *My family comprises five persons* in Deutsch.

I can think of two sentences as given below:

1. Meine Familie umfasst fünf Personen.
2. Fünf Personen umfasst meine Familie.

Which of these two is the correct form?

Comment: Both are correct grammar. The second sentence puts strong emphasis on the object. However, I would translate the English sentence as "Meine Familie besteht aus fünf Personen."

Comment: @Roland. That's basically the answer

Comment: Actually this has not much to do with *umfassen* - the answer would be the same with almost any other transitive verb.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. It only depends on what you'd like to emphasize.

Your first one is the more common sentence structure (subject - verb - object). You would normally want to use that.

You may prefer to use the second one (object - verb - subject) if the part "Fünf Personen" is the most important information that you aim to convey, and the rest of the sentence is less important or more self-evident in the context.

English still has remnants of something comparable (although not the same) in sentences like the second one here:

> A: Wanna go have a beer?
> B: **That** I can get behind!

Comment: Interesting! Do both these sentences translate to "My family includes / comprises five persons"? In English "five persons comprise my family" is considered incorrect to my knowledge. One could say "five persons constitute my family" instead.

Comment: @SajjadHossain English is an [SVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object) language. German is a [V2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order) language.

Comment: Yes they both mean the same. Note that a literal translation to English would be "Five persons include**s** my family". The form of the verb (being singular) makes it clear in this sentence that "meine Familie" (singular) is the subject, becaus it fits the verb,  and "fünf Personen" (plural) must be the object, regardless of their position. "Fünf Personen" is also accusative case, but accidentally, there is no difference between nominative case and accusative case for the expression "fünf Personen".

Comment: So would "Fünf Personnen umfassten meine Familie" be wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that would be wrong, because "meine Familie" is the subject of the sentence and singular.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a little flexibility with your question, here is a third possibility of describing the composition of "my family":

```
Meine Familie besteht aus fünf Personen.

My family consists of five people.
```